# What does the CMP stand for in CMake policy?

Tags: cmake

I failed to find out what do C, M, and P stand for in CMake in the official documents. For example, why not POLICY0077 instead of CMP0077.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding was always that it is an abbreviation from "C Make Policy".